# How do I show data which depends on data from another String in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 selection boxes, which show an AlertDialog. The first one shows an listview.builder in the alertdialog with the options of 'Havo' or 'Vwo'. When the user selects Havo , the options 1-5 must be shown in the second alert dialog. When the user selects Vwo, the options 1-6 must be shown in the second alertdialog.

This is my list which holds the data:
(Also holds other data, please ignore)

```
    const LEVELS = [
      Level(level: 'Vwo', subjects: [
        'Nederlandse taal en literatuur',
        'Engelse taal en literatuur',
        'Frans',
        'Duits',
        'Maatschappijleer',
        'Culturele en kunstzinnige vorming',
        'Lichamelijke opvoeding',
        'Grieks',
        'Latijn',
        'Wiskunde A',
        'Wiskunde C',
        'Wiskunde B',
        'Natuurkunde',
        'Scheikunde',
        'Biologie',
        'Economie',
        'Geschiedenis',
        'Informatica',
        'Bedrijfseconomie',
        'Spaans'
      ], years: [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5',
        '6'
      ]),
      Level(level: 'Havo', subjects: [
        'Nederlands',
        'Engels',
        'Mens en natuur',
        'Mens en maatschappij',
        'Kunst en cultuur',
        'Bewegen en sport',
        'Duits',
        'Frans',
      ], years: [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5'
      ])
    ];
```

This is how my code is built up:

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    import '../../models/studyOptionsModel.dart';
    
    class SetupScreenThreeForm extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _SetupScreenThreeFormState createState() => _SetupScreenThreeFormState();
    }
    
    class _SetupScreenThreeFormState extends State<SetupScreenThreeForm> {
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      var _isLoginPage = false;
      var _schoolLevel = 'Niveau';
      var _classYear = 'Klas';
      var _bestSubjects = '';
    
      var selectionOptions = LEVELS.toList();
    
      //The alertdialog for setting the level
      createAlertDialog(BuildContext context, selectionType) {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return Dialog(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7E36EC),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: selectionOptions.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _schoolLevel = selectionOptions[index].level;
                                    print(_schoolLevel);
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  });
                                },
                                child: ListTile(
                                    leading: Text(
                                  selectionOptions[index].level,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      fontSize: 14),
                                ))),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ));
            });
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                child: InkWell(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                    color: Color(0xFF7E36EC),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        _schoolLevel,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      createAlertDialog(context, 'level');
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                child: InkWell(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                    color: Color(0xFF7E36EC),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        _classYear,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      createAlertDialog(context, 'years');
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                child: InkWell(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                    color: Color(0xFF212121),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        'Sterkste vakken',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 50,
                child: InkWell(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                    color: Color(0xFF212121),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        'Minst sterkste vakken',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use if statement and if the condition is true do the following:

```
if (userselection=='Havo'){
LEVELS.length(x) //x is the number of levels you want to show for example for 4 levels x=3
}
```